# Is it of any help to edit old downvoted questions to recover the ability to ask questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that has 2 downvotes and am blocked from asking questions.

I keep editing it but wonder if it is of any use because I assume there is no actual review of the edits and that no-one will see the question again. Please let me know if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: Edits bump a question. If the edit actually improves the question then why not? If not, you can ask a new question 6 months after the last one. The duplicate target explains all that.

Comment: No it does not help, Jeanne

Comment: Bumping means it is treated as a new one?

Comment: Bumping means it shows up in [the active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active) of the home page where it will get more views

Comment: "No it does not help, Jeanne" Did you read it? It contains all the necessary info and actually does answer your question.

Comment: You're not blocked because of a single downvotes question - you probably have more deleted ones

Comment: You have 5 deleted questions, with scores <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/64650688) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/63870509) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/63862657) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/63848255) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/63833325)

Comment: Simply *making an edit* doesn't help anything, no. In fact, if you make an edit that improves nothing, then bumping it with an edit is likely to just attract more downvotes, which is the opposite of helpful. You have to actually *improve* the question.

Answer (score 6):

The age of the post does not matter. Edit every post that needs editing. Remove all fluff, all unrelated information. Make sure the post is easy to read and clearly describes the topic.

However, at some point, you realize that there's nothing else that can be improved. And that's ok. If you still don't get upvotes then the system will give you a chance for redemption every 6 months. You can use that time to think about the best question possible. You have all this time to write the question, edit it and improve before posting on Stack Overflow.